# How to correctly position timestamp in list item?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to create a list item that looks like your typical inbox message.

[image: inbox message]

The demo shown in the [components docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#avatar-list) shows the timestamp being added as an `ion-note` but is missing in markup provided.

When I inspect the demo HTML, it seems classes like `item-inner` and `input-wrapper` are used. I can't seem to find information about them anywhere.

Do I write my own CSS to lay these things out or is there a correct ionic way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a while ago but haven't got around to answering my own question. Here it is.

My `ion-item` markup:

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
  <ion-avatar item-left>
    <img src="http://i.pravatar.cc/80?u=judywong">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>Jane Doe</h2>
  <ion-note item-right>4:00 pm</ion-note>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor…</p>
</ion-item>
```

Then I use CSS to position it to the top while using `item-right` attribute to position to the right the ionic way.

```
ion-note {
  align-self: flex-start;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: $item-ios-padding-right/2;
}
```

Also added some right padding to `h2` to clear the timestamp.